# simple BPMN ecore metamodel

Tags: bpmn, metamodel, ecore, mda

I'm trying to build my own simple BPMN ecore metamodel by simplifying built one by OMG specification, with little change on dependencies between elements.

Here my own metamodel:[image]

Would you please give me any guidelines that make sure that my metamodel is correct?

Answer (score 0):

When you write "correct" you need to specify with respect to which one.
If you mean with respect to BPMN2 standard, then you need to compare your metamodel with the standard one.